# Attribute "aria-current='page'" with class='active' not disappearing from first NavLink even after clicking the other links

Tags: reactjs, class, hyperlink

In my DOM, my elements look like this:

```
<nav>
   <a aria-current="page" class="item_1 active" href="/">Home</a>
   <a class="item_2" href="/about">About</a>
   <a aria-current="page" class="item_3 active" href="/blog">Blog</a>
   <a class="item_4" href="/contact">Contact</a>
</nav>
```

Even after clicking the third link, the first link is not changing its attribute and class.

Supposed I have the Menu Component:

```
import React from 'react'
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom'

function Menu(props) {
   const list = [{
      item: 'Home',
      itemLink: '/'
   }, {
      item: 'About',
      itemLink: '/about'
   }, {
      item: 'Blog',
      itemLink: '/blog'
   }, {
      item: 'Contact',
      itemLink: '/contact'
   }]
   const menuItems = list.map((list, index) => {
      return <NavLink className={`item_${index + 1}`} to={`${list.itemLink}`} key={index}> <span>{list.item}</span></NavLink >
   })

   return(
      <nav className="navmenu">{menuItems}</nav>
   )
}

export default Menu
```

And the Main Component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Menu from './Menu'
import Home from './Home'
import About from './About'
import Contact from './Contact'
import Blog from './Blog'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom'

class Main extends Component {
   render() {
      return (
         <Router>
            <div>
               <Menu />
               <Switch>
                 <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
                 <Route path='/about' component={About} />
                 <Route path='/blog' component={Blog} />
                 <Route path='/contact' component={Contact} />
               </Switch>  
            </div>
         </Router>
      )
   }
}

export default Main
```

How can I make the current link when clicked or hit the back button, will have the attributes (aria-current="page" class="active") set only to the current link and not on the siblings?

Comment: you have two `aria-current` and `class='active'`.

Comment: @JosephD. That's right. I'm new to ReactJS and I don't even know why it's not disappearing after clicking the other links.

Comment: Can you post the `list` also?

Comment: @ravibagul91. Kindly check the edited post.

Comment: Can you show your Route?

Comment: @ravibagul91. Post was edited, kindly check.

Comment: Dave, this is very strange now. I got the temporary solution for you but I'll advise to raise a concern with the community. Usually this should not happen, but they might have missed this in the `react-router-dom v5` release. The solution for your situation is, to add [`exact`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/NavLink/exact-bool) prop on `NavLink`.

Answer (score 2):

Based ib @ravibagul91, the solution would be revealed by adding exact prop in NavLink.

```
const menuItems = list.map((list, index) => {
   return <NavLink className={`item_${index + 1}`} to={`${list.itemLink}`} key={index} exact> <span>{list.item}</span></NavLink >
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I was stumped on this for a couple of days.
I just wanted to update this as of React-Router 6.

The *exact* attribute is now *end*.

Official documentation states: **If the end prop is used, it will ensure this component isn't matched as "active" when its descendant paths are matched". This used to be what exact did.**